# Opening Python script in Ruby mode is not working

Tags: python, ruby, stdout, apriltags, python-3.9

Trying out the new "Ruby Mode" in Python 3.9, but am having trouble getting it working:

Simple script in `mymodule`:

```
puts "Hello World"
```

Expected output when executing the file in ruby mode ("rb") was for "Hello World" printed on stdout, but I'm getting an error:

```
>>> with open("mymodule", mode="rb") as f:
...     for line in f:
...         exec(line)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1
    puts "Hello World"
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It looks like the lines are being correctly parsed as `rb"ruby style lines"`, so it's clearly not [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#open) at fault:

```
>>> line.strip() == rb'puts "Hello World"'
True
```

What's wrong here? That must be a bug in [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#exec), right?

Comment: what is this `Ruby Mode`? can you post a link about this? I can't find any info

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an April Fools joke and April Fools is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a file in Ruby mode has to be lead by a Ruby shebang.  Try using:

```
#!/usr/april/fools/ruby
puts "Hello World"
```